# Convert string to BSTR

Tags: visual-c++

From the following function, I use the path. Now I generate some lets say list of names separated by newline

```
 func(BSTR * path)
 {

  // From path paramter client sent, I use the path. 

   //Now I generate some lets say list of names separated by newline

   string output = "Bob\n Rob \n Lilly \n";


   // Now client wants the path to be modified with the output

  // So i did the following 

SysFreeString(*path);
*path= SysAllocStringByteLen(output.c_str(), output.size());

  }
```

Is the last two lines correct. Somehow testing doesnot seems ok !

Comment: What "does not seem OK" exactly?

Comment: I was trying to check the contents of path, via debugger after the SysAllocStringByteLen. It looked like chinease characters

Comment: A BSTR needs to store a utf-16 encoded string to be recognizable to debuggers and almost any library.  std::wstring in C++.  SysAllocStringByteLen is an ancient hack to store an 8-bit encoded string, valid in some ancient languages whose runtimes are now long forgotten.  Fixed-length strings in Basic is the only one I know of.  Yes, looks like Chinese.  As written the fix is simple, just use wstring instead of string so you can use SysAllocString/Len.

Comment: Thanks Hans, But then i need to convert the string to wstring.

Comment: Thanks Hans, i converted the string to wstring and everything worked like magic. (But overhead is i need to convert it back to BSTR, but as long as it works its ok). This function is interface to client and i cant change its parameters

Comment: @Hans : If you add your as answer Ill accept it. (It has nice explanation also). Im new to windows and helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: An alternative ... If you're using Visual C++ anyways, you can use the CString class, the class has an AllocSysString() method.